# Bash Multiple -execdir or -exec statements NOT WORKING when divided over multiple lines for proper code formatting

Tags: bash, git, find, exec, git-bash

As I already indicated in the question, I must have multiple commands to be executed in a sub-directory when `find` sees that a particular directory exists in that sub-directory.

Now when I have only one `-execdir` statement in `find` clause then it works just fine like below:

```
find $repoFolder -type d -name '*.git' \
    -execdir git config --global credential.helper manager{}/.git \;
```

BUT when I have multiple `-execdir` statements and if I divide them on multiple lines for code to look decent, it doesn't work, which doesn't make sense at all, it SHOULD work:

```
find $repoFolder -type d -name '*.git' \
    -execdir git config --global credential.helper manager{}/.git \; \
    -execdir curr_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD){}/.git \; \
    -execdir git checkout master && git remote prune origin{}/.git \; \
    -execdir git pull && git pull origin{}/.git \; \
    -execdir git checkout $curr_branch && git merge master{}/.git \;
```

Can anyone help in finding out why is it giving following error ?

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
find: missing argument to `-execdir'
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
find: missing argument to `-execdir'
....
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems. First, each `-execdir` executes its command in a new shell process; `curr_branch` isn't defined beyond its own shell. Second, the `&&` terminates the `find` command (prematurely, as no `\;` was ever found).

You need to combine everything into a single compound shell command for use with a single `-execdir` primary.

```
find "$repoFolder" -type d -name '*.git' \
  -execdir sh -c '
      git config --global credential.helper manager"$1"/.git;
      curr_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"$1"/.git;
      git checkout master && git remote prune origin"$1"/.git;
      git pull && git pull origin"$1"/.git;
      git checkout $curr_branch && git merge master"$1"/.git' _ {} \;
```

It's not clear how you are actually using the directory name in each command; I've simply replaced each use of `{}` with `"$1"` as it was found; this may not work as you want, though.

Comment: I don't know how your original was support to work either, but this is how you need to structure multiple commands that depend on each other. If you find a directory named `foo.git`, what is `managerfoo.git/.git` supposed to be?

Comment: Did some googling about the use of execdir ,it said you need to pass the directory path as argument which we could do by {} or $1, but in this case it seems if I need to run only git based commands, I don't need to use the argument notion anymore, right ? Also I was expecting multiple `exec` or `execdir` statement were able to be line-separated with bash in any editor wthout using single execdir and quoting which sounds very ambiguous, are you sure there is no elseway of having multiple execdir statements which doesn't use quotes around commands and can be spanned over multiple lines ?

Comment: The words following `-exec` (and `-execdir`) are passed directly to an `exec` system call, with `{}` being replaced by the current file, with no shell involvement. (The arguments themselves are subject to shell processing before `find` runs, of course.)